# Как оформить прямую речь при одновременных высказываниях

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

В тех учебниках, что я читал, этот вопрос не обсуждался. В книгах почти не встречал (мало читаю). Вот недавно наткнулся в книге на такое оформление:

- Здорово! Ужасно! - одновременно сказали я и Наив (с) (имеется в виду, что каждый сказал по одному слову)

Но мне это кажется идущим против рекомендации касаемо ясности текста. А ставить слова автора перед прямой речью в данном случае не хочется. Поэтому я почитал правила и выдвинул такой вариант:

"Здорово!" - "Ужасно!" - одновременно сказали я и Наив.

Вопрос: это моя авторская пунктуация, или такое встречается в литературе? И какие еще могут быть варианты оформления? Хотелось бы как можно больше примеров из литературы.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: Когда будет исчерпывающий - обязательно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По правилам будет так:
**-Здорово! Ужасно! - одновременно сказали я и Наив.**
Без кавычек еще и удобнее.

Приведу пример:
**- Антуан!  Лорелея! - одновременно воскликнули они, не замечая ничего и
никого вокруг.**
Оливия Карент. Кракле

**Дополнение**

Вспомните "Маугли".  В этом отрывке, кроме Багиры, говорят безымянные члены стаи.  А ведь все понятно:

-Правильно, правильно, – ***ответили вечно голодные молодые волки.*** – Слушайте Багиру. Детёныша можно купить за известную цену. Так говорит Закон.

– Я знаю, что не имею здесь права голоса, а потому прошу у вас позволения говорить.

– Говори, – ***послышалось двадцать голосов.***

– Позорно убить безволосого детёныша... Трудно ли принять решение?

***Поднялся гул голосов, звучало:***
– Стоит ли рассуждать? Он умрёт от зимних дождей; солнце сожжёт его! Какой вред может принести нам безволосая лягушка? Пусть себе бегает со стаей. А где бык, Багира? Примем детёныша!

**Дополнение к дополнению**

**1**.   ...***и все затараторили хором***: "Ничего страшного, дорогая, мы тебе поможем" (папа),  "Я сейчас же позвоню доктору Тейду" (мама),  "А сколько голосов ты слышишь?" (Коломба) и т.д.
 Мюриель Барбери.  Элегантность ёжика

**2.**    ***Малыши*** детского сада на вопрос "Почему нужно делать зарядку?", ***перебивая друг друга, отвечают:*** "Чтобы ручки и ножки сильные были!",  "Чтобы не болеть!",  "Потому что весело!".

**3.**   ***Ребята*** помолчали, переглянулись, и тут   ***кто-то из них***  предложил: "А мы его по очереди в школу водить будем."
— И домой провожать.
— И уроки поможем делать, —   ***перебивая друг друга, защебетали одноклассники.***